# Get Attribute "duration" from the html contained in my javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I have got a variable in javascript in which i get the HTML as follows,

```
<li duration="1000"></li>
```

How can i get the attribute duration from it using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

With [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute):

```
yourElement.getAttribute('duration')
```

Note that there is no `duration` attribute in HTML so your code is not HTML. If you want to add arbitrary attributes to hold data for JavaScript, then use [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Then you could:

```
<li data-duration="1000"></li>
```

and

```
yourElement.dataset.duration
```

Comment: Thanks Quentin for you rply